# Is there a way to automatically propagate NULL in purrr::map?

Tags: r, functional-programming, tidyverse, purrr

I have some data, some of which is replicated, some not. I can only fit
my model for the replicated data.

```
library(tidyverse)
d <- tribble(
  ~env, ~val,
  "A",  1,
  "A",  2,
  "B",  3
)
```

I am using `tidyr::nest()` and `purrr::map()` functions to fit my model. 
However, in every function I use for `map()` I had to cater for the special
case that a particular set of data is not modellable, which i archieved
via calls in the style of

```
map(col, function(elem){ if(!is.null(elem)) DO_STUFF(elem) else NULL})
```

After a while, I managed to extract this behaviour to a purrr-style adverb
function which takes another function and wraps it such that this behaviour
for `NULL` elements is automatic:

```
maybe <- function(fun){
  function(val,...){ if(!is.null(val)) fun(val, ...) else NULL}
}
```

However, this left me wondering: **Am I duplicating behaviour which is
already archievable using tidyverse functions?**

*Bonus question: Is there a word in functional programming for a function like `maybe`?*

---

This is an example to test my adverb:

Simple Model: A mean for data in environment A and no model for data in 
environment B (since the data is unreplicated:)

```
modelFuns <- list(A = mean, B = NULL)
```

Group data by environment and determine the appropriate model for each group

```
d <- d %>% group_by(env) %>% nest(.key = "data")
d %<>% mutate(model = modelFuns[env])
d

## # A tibble: 2 x 3
##   env   data             model 
##   <chr> <list>           <list>
## 1 A     <tibble [2 × 1]> <fn>  
## 2 B     <tibble [1 × 1]> <NULL>
```

Perform modelling:

```
d %<>% mutate(out = pmap(list(model, data), maybe(function(m,d) m(d$val))))
d

## # A tibble: 2 x 4
##   env   data             model  out      
##   <chr> <list>           <list> <list>   
## 1 A     <tibble [2 × 1]> <fn>   <dbl [1]>
## 2 B     <tibble [1 × 1]> <NULL> <NULL>
```

Which is equivalent to the following code which does not use my `maybe` adverb:

```
d %<>% mutate(out = pmap(list(model, data), function(m,d){if(!is.null(m)) m(d$val) else NULL}))
d

## # A tibble: 2 x 4
##   env   data             model  out      
##   <chr> <list>           <list> <list>   
## 1 A     <tibble [2 × 1]> <fn>   <dbl [1]>
## 2 B     <tibble [1 × 1]> <NULL> <NULL>
```

The fact that there might be a value or there might be `NULL` propagates to 
everything I want to do with the modelling results downstream, which is
why the adverb `maybe` is useful. Does something like this already exist
in the tidyverse?

```
isModelNice <- function(val) val > 0
d %<>% mutate(nice = map(out, maybe(isModelNice)))
d

## # A tibble: 2 x 5
##   env   data             model  out       nice     
##   <chr> <list>           <list> <list>    <list>   
## 1 A     <tibble [2 × 1]> <fn>   <dbl [1]> <lgl [1]>
## 2 B     <tibble [1 × 1]> <NULL> <NULL>    <NULL>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

could you use `purrr::possibly()`?

```
library(tidyverse)

d <- tribble(
  ~env, ~val,
  "A",  1,
  "A",  2,
  "B",  3
)

modelFuns <- list(A = mean, B = NULL)

d %>% group_by(env) %>% 
  nest(.key = "data") %>% 
  mutate(model = modelFuns[env]) %>% 
  mutate(out = pmap(list(model, data), possibly(function(m,d) m(d$val), NULL)))
```

Comment: OK, this works if my model function throws an error if I give a NULL value. Not exactly the behaviour I looked for (what if my model function returns `numeric(0)` or whatever given a `NULL` argument), but might be  working for this particular case.